# Fatal error: Out of memory Zend Error / PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, phpmyadmin, wamp

I am using WAMP for my application. I am developing the application in ZEND. When I work with the application I am receiving the following Error. Even I am not able to look at my PHPMYADMIN. The error totally vanish my WAMP!!  I am using WampServer2.1e-x32

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1048576) (tried to allocate 393216 bytes) in 

D:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\libraries\config.default.php on line 2051
```

I have did the following but still I issue remains same:

I have set the memory limit to 0 in php.ini files. Googled and found if we send the memory limit to 0 then it will take unlimited. Also tried `32M,64M,128M`. some specified 1G tried that too.

Tried setting `ini_set('memory_limit','16M'); ,32M and 256M` no use.(Even tried up to 16384M)

Do I want to increase the Execution time? Will it help?

This out of memory message has happened to me before when I have tried to create arrays that were just to large to be sensible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087183/fatal-error-out-of-memory tried all the advice from the comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following solution and it works well!

Inside my `wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\config.inc.php` file below the line 24 I added the following code:

```
$cfg['MemoryLimit']  = '128M';
```

And It works well;

After inserting Line 19-25 in my `config.inc.php` file:

```
/* End of servers configuration */

$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en-utf-8';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
$cfg['MemoryLimit'] = '128M';
```

Hope this will help some one!!

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me. 
I'm posting my problem below.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately TomPHP's advice didn't work for me.

From error log:

```
[22-May-2013 10:10:15 Europe/Warsaw] memory_limit: 512M
[22-May-2013 10:10:15 Europe/Warsaw] memory_limit: 512M
[22-May-2013 10:10:15 Europe/Warsaw] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 89128960) (tried to allocate 82575361 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/ksiegarniawarszawa.pl/public_html/pma/export.php on line 377
[22-May-2013 10:10:15 Europe/Warsaw] PHP Stack trace:
[22-May-2013 10:10:15 Europe/Warsaw] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/vhosts/ksiegarniawarszawa.pl/public_html/pma/export.php:0
[22-May-2013 10:10:15 Europe/Warsaw] PHP   2. ExportSql->exportData() /var/www/vhosts/ksiegarniawarszawa.pl/public_html/pma/export.php:843
[22-May-2013 10:10:15 Europe/Warsaw] PHP   3. PMA_exportOutputHandler() /var/www/vhosts/ksiegarniawarszawa.pl/public_html/pma/libraries/plugins/export/ExportSql.class.php:1845
```

Notice, that it's "Out of memory", not "Memory exhausted" like in a normal case when PHP memory_limit is reached.

Comment: Did you found any alternative?

Comment: Try with '128M' I read some where the max in 128M.. may be it might work.. :)

Comment: It seems that it's a strange problem with nested buffering... Helped for me something like this: if (ob_get_level() > 1) ob_end_flush();  Strange, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

This additional configuration line works not for me (LAMP). If this error occurs I have to switch to an older version of PMA